Why is a request with URL containing ../../../ rejected with 400 by AWS Application Load Balancer?
I have an Angular webapp talking to a .NET backend.
One of my endpoints takes a user defined id as part of the URL, i.e. /owner/config/{id}
When testing locally on my PC, this all works exactly as expected, but when deployed to AWS (ECS) I am getting some URLs rejected, but only with specific configurations of id's. The requests appear to be getting rejected by the Application Load Balancer as the log shows they are not forwarded to the target.
Note, I URI encode the id component to cater for reserved characters such as /
I have enabled the load balancer logs and see some unexpected behaviour.



id
Logged Request
Status code




test
GET https://client.mydomain.com:443/owner/config/test HTTP/2.0
200


../../test
GET https://client.mydomain.com:443/owner/config/..%2F..%2Ftest HTTP/2.0
200


../../../test
GET https://client.mydomain.com:443- HTTP/2.0
400



The requests with two sets of ../ work fine, but with three the log shows a - for the subdirectory part of the url and returns a 400. As far as I can tell, the URL is correctly formed.
The load balancer listener rules are very simple, it checks the "Http Host Header" matches "client.mydomain.com" and forwards it to the AWS target group. There is a default rule to return 503 if no other rules are matched, so it's not hitting that.
I have also tested from Postman to rule out any Angular peculiarities but get the same results.
I've tried manually encoding the "periods" ti %2e, but this had no effect either.

I assume it's AWS blocking path traversals because insecure handling of ../ requests is unfortunately common. Do you have a good reason for wanting to support .. for a web-service? I can't think of any legitimate reasons at my end...

I think you may be right, however as it's URI encoded, and that it allows ../../ I'm confused by the behaviour. Maybe because three ../s would take you back beyond the root.
A quick google shows that this can get blocked by the AWS WAF, but I don't have WAF enabled currently.
As for the use case,  we allow used to enter their own id and it was noted that this caused a problem, I agree it's an odd value and we could block it in the client entry dialog, but I want to understand why it's happening.

/owner/config/../test is the same as /owner/test, and /owner/config/../../test is the same as /test - while ../../../test would be ../test which is above the site root, so that seems fine to me.

However /owner/config/../test is actually sent as /owner/config/..%2F..%2Ftest and so it does call my /owner/config/{id} endpoint.
It's odd that behaviour.
